# how to set my Intellij-idea UI theme?

Tags: intellij-idea

I remember there should be 2 type of theme, how to add the light one?

Here are the settings:
[image: intellij preference]

Comment: Default theme might be the light one. Just try.

Comment: Oh, that's odd....my intellij has different settings....is default "light"?

Answer (score 3):

you can find the setting in:

```
file > settings > appearance & behavior > appearance > ui options > theme
```

you want to set the setting to `IntelliJ`, then press apply.

the light theme you are looking for should be `IntelliJ`. the dark theme is `Dracula`...and there is also a surprise `Windows` theme.